# Installing spaCy on anaconda on macos

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda, conda, spacy

**My environment**

python2.7 running on Anaconda version 2019.10.
macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

**The problem**

I cannot seem to install the package spaCy on python. I have followed the documentation of spaCy (https://spacy.io/usage) to no avail. I have tried conda, pip and installing from source.

**Reproducing the problem**

`conda install` (takes a long time then gets stuck)

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ max$ sudo conda install -c conda-forge spacy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ (gets stuck here)
```

`pip install`

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ max$ pip install -U spacy

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting spacy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/db/499f374339b522b6618234b93f25d2990692795ccce3152519ccc508586c/spacy-2.3.2.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-build-env-Hm0sIw/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
       cwd: None
  Complete output (191 lines):
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/b7/182161210a13158cd3ccc41ee19aadef54496b74f2817cc147006ec932b4/setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/00/3df031b3ecd5444d572141321537080b40c1c25e1caa3d86cdd12e5e919c/wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/a7/6f692f3535e736d13add7841b9ee2ec5997832b26b72decc928f62404986/Cython-0.29.21-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/8d/d095bbb109a004351c85c83bc853782fc27692693b305dd7b170c36a1262/cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/44/f244c9b1c8d5ca79e0afdd20e04a93b45160f1541f9904c44673bb8e48d1/preshed-3.0.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/be/1a824e7faeb786af7e9931a29034f09d877e3340c536dc9bf10f65b4d422/murmurhash-1.0.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
  Collecting thinc==7.4.1
  Collecting pathlib==1.0.1; python_version < "3.4" (from thinc==7.4.1)
  Collecting catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/f9/9a5658e2f56932e41eb264941f9a2cb7f3ce41a80cb36b2af6ab78e2f8af/catalogue-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/28/ffb9f0b940041aeaec2194e840b5ffe19d0ae252de89579fa8b810174d9f/srsly-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/7e/281edb5bc3274dfb894d90f4dbacfceaca381c2435ec6187a2c6f329aed7/tqdm-4.48.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/85/40b8f66c2dd8f4fd9f09d59b22720cffecf1331e788b8a0cab5bafb353d1/plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/e0/7f618f18497135cc98f0a09ccaaad795efe044b7e2cfd3f4251acb2a9d0a/blis-0.4.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/96/84cf406fe7d589f3dba9fc0f737e65985a3526c6d8c783f02d4b5a10825d/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc==7.4.1)
  Collecting importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8" (from catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/58/cdea07eb51fc2b906db0968a94700866fc46249bdc75cac23f9d13168929/importlib_metadata-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting zipp>=0.5 (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/0a/67556e9b7782df7118c1f49bdc494da5e5e429c93aa77965f33e81287c8c/zipp-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting contextlib2; python_version < "3" (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/60/370352f7ef6aa96c52fb001831622f50f923c1d575427d021b8ab3311236/contextlib2-0.6.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting pathlib2; python_version < "3" (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/45/9c82d3666af4ef9f221cbb954e1d77ddbb513faf552aea6df5f37f1a4859/pathlib2-2.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting configparser>=3.5; python_version < "3" (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/2a/95ed0501cf5d8709490b1d3a3f9b5cf340da6c433f896bbe9ce08dbe6785/configparser-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting six (from pathlib2; python_version < "3"->importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version < "3"->importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->thinc==7.4.1)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cymem, srsly
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cymem (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-wheel-k463Ej --python-tag cp27
         cwd: /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/
    Complete output (25 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    copying cymem/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    copying cymem/about.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    package init file 'cymem/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/tests
    copying cymem/tests/test_import.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/tests
    copying cymem/cymem.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    copying cymem/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    copying cymem/cymem.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    running build_ext
    building 'cymem.cymem' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c cymem/cymem.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/cymem.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
    clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Applications/anaconda2/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/cymem.o -L/Applications/anaconda2/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/cymem.so
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cymem
    Running setup.py clean for cymem
    Building wheel for srsly (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for srsly (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/srsly/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/srsly/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-wheel-eooA7v --python-tag cp27
         cwd: /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/srsly/
    Complete output (86 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/_msgpack_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/about.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/_json_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    copying srsly/_pickle_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/ujson/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/_msgpack_numpy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/_ext_type.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/cloudpickle/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/cloudpickle
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests
    copying srsly/tests/test_msgpack_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests
    copying srsly/tests/test_json_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests
    copying srsly/tests/test_pickle_api.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests
    copying srsly/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/ujson
    copying srsly/tests/ujson/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/ujson
    copying srsly/tests/ujson/test_ujson.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/ujson
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_extension.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_subtype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_buffer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_unpack.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_pack.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_except.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_case.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_read_size.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_memoryview.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_seq.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_limits.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_newspec.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_numpy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_format.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_stricttype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    copying srsly/tests/msgpack/test_sequnpack.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/msgpack
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/tests/cloudpickle/testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/tests/cloudpickle/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/tests/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_file_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/tests/cloudpickle
    copying srsly/ujson/ujson.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/ujson/JSONtoObj.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/ujson/objToJSON.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/ujson/version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/ujson/py_defines.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/ujson
    copying srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/_packer.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/sysdep.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/pack.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/unpack_define.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/buff_converter.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/unpack.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/pack_template.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    copying srsly/msgpack/unpack_template.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    running build_ext
    building 'srsly.msgpack._unpacker' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I. -I/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/srsly/include -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.o -O2 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
    clang: warning: include path for libstdc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    In file included from srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.cpp:615:
    srsly/msgpack/unpack.h:277:45: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]
        py = PyObject_CallFunction(u->ext_hook, "(is#)", (int)typecode, pos, (Py_ssize_t)length-1);
                                                ^
    1 warning generated.
    g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Applications/anaconda2/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.o -L/Applications/anaconda2/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/srsly/msgpack/_unpacker.so -Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../../srsly/platform/darwin/lib -lstdc++ -lm
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for srsly
    Running setup.py clean for srsly
  Failed to build cymem srsly
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, cython, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, pathlib, contextlib2, zipp, six, scandir, pathlib2, configparser, importlib-metadata, catalogue, srsly, tqdm, plac, numpy, blis, wasabi, thinc
    Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-record-CJ7M9x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-build-env-Hm0sIw/overlay --compile
           cwd: /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/
      Complete output (10 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'cymem/tests/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/anaconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/Applications/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c cymem/cymem.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/cymem/cymem.o -O3 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
      clang: error: no such file or directory: 'cymem/cymem.cpp'
      clang: error: no input files
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-install-E3v5tl/cymem/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-record-CJ7M9x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-build-env-Hm0sIw/overlay --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/anaconda2/bin/python /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/k2/yfz74q0j1zq0_bgpcfvfj7br0000gn/T/pip-build-env-Hm0sIw/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1 Check the logs for full command output.
```

`from source`

cloning works fine

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy
cd spaCy
```

the following `pip install` doesn't:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -U spacy-lookups-data
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The error:

```
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ max$ pip install -U spacy-lookups-data
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already up-to-date: spacy-lookups-data in /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in /Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from spacy-lookups-data) (41.4.0)
(base) MacBook-Pro:~ max$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: _`(base) MacBook-Pro:~ max$ sudo conda install -c conda-forge spacy`_ Don't use the base environment for development!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new env instead:

```
conda create -n my_env spacy python=2.7
```

changing the Python version to what you require and including whatever additional specs you need at creation time. Conda tends to work much smoother if one separates concerns and creates environments on per task or per project basis.

Side note: using `pip` in the **base** env is usually a bad idea. See "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)".